# NSScanner simple question on iphone

Tags: iphone, nsscanner

**my string is k= /Users/applefan/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/3.1.3/Applications/422B3239-F521-4985-89FE-EC778C57C0AB/Documents/1.sql**

now  how to get **1 from 1.sql**

i did somethins like this

```
            NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:storePath];
        [scanner scanUpToString:@".sql" intoString:&k]  ;           
            NSLog(@"test is %@",k);
```

i did this also

```
unsigned int intValue;

                while([scanner isAtEnd] == NO) {
                    [scanner scanHexInt:&intValue];
                    NSLog(@"HEX : %d", intValue);       
                **}
```

it gives me all the int value**

but i only want the numeric  value after  **/Documents/**

Comment: We need a little bit more information about your particular case. If the string is in that exact format every time, you can just do `[NSString stringByRemovingOcurrencesOfString: withString:];` If it's a little more complicated than that, we can investigate other options.

Comment: i just need the numeric value after Documents/ thats it , whatever the value is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *k = @"/Users/applefan/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/3.1.3/Applications/422B3239-F521-4985-89FE-EC778C57C0AB/Documents/1.sql";
NSString *one = [[[[k componentsSeparatedByString:@"Documents/"] objectAtIndex:1] 
   componentsSeparatedByString:@".sql"] objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"Is it one? %@", one);
```